# How to get a Task to return to the UI thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

Background: I'm relatively experienced in C#, but completely new to WPF.

I have a WPF application that will be used internally for some simple monitoring. I have a database call and the data that's returned is then displayed in a tree view,
and while this happens there's an overlay that reads "Loading..." before the data comes back. My current implementation looks like this:

```
await WithOverlay("Loading...", async () =>
{
    MyControl.Items = await _database.Retrieve(messageSummary.Id);
});
```

where `WithOverlay` looks like this:

```
private async Task WithOverlay(string overlayMessage, Func<Task> func)
{
    Overlay.Content = overlayMessage;
    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    await func();

    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Now, this works just fine, but since a lot of times (depending on what exactly the user is looking at elsewhere in the application) the database call comes back really
quickly the "Loading..." overlay just appears as an annoying flicker. It's only a small thing but it's bothering me so I decided that I could fix it by putting in a small 
delay *before* the overlay appears; say, a quarter of a second. This was my attempt at modifying the `WithOverlay` method:

```
private async Task WithOverlay(string overlayMessage, Func<Task> func)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    var overlayTask = Task.Delay(250, token).ContinueWith(_ => {
        Overlay.Content = overlayMessage;
        Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    });

    await func();

    if (token.CanBeCanceled) tokenSource.Cancel();

    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

My idea was to:

- create a task with a delay of 250 milliseconds that will, on completion, display the overlay
- await the wrapped function
- when the wrapped function completes, if the overlay task hasn't finished yet then cancel it
- hide the overlay (regardless of its current state)

Unfortunately though this doesn't work; on the line `Overlay.Content = overlayMessage` I get the exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'".

I have a suspicion that this has something to do with the Task's synchronisation context (if I recall my tech demos correctly) but I can't figure out how to control that to get the continuation
to resume on the same thread.

Comment: You could try `DispatcherTimer` instead of tasks or use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to do the marshalling.

Comment: You would have to await the `func` and the `overlayTask` simultaneously, with WhenAny(). But I think using a Timer is cleaner.

Comment: This IMHO is the best explanation on async/await which really helped me and may help you too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qiB3oW_nd8

Comment: @bommelding thanks for your comment. I'm curious how you would accomplish this with a timer, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: When you've got this working, how about a database call that takes 260 ms?  You didn't really solve anything here, just moved the problem around.

Comment: As an alternative, always show thew message. For a minimum of say, 100 or 200 ms.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True, I didn't solve the problem, but vastly reduced its frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate a `TaskScheduler` with the continuation task to force the delegate that sets the `Content` and `Visibility` properties to be set on the UI thread:

```
var overlayTask = Task.Delay(250, token).ContinueWith(_ => {
    Overlay.Content = overlayMessage;
    Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer, @mm8. Okay, so I accomplished it like this, I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on whether this is worse than your anwser:

```
    private async Task WithOverlay(string overlayMessage, Func<Task> func)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(250);
        var wrappedTask = func();

        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(delayTask, wrappedTask);

        if (completedTask == delayTask)
        {
            Overlay.Content = overlayMessage;
            Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        await wrappedTask;

        Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

So, I start a task *that is just a 250ms delay*. I start the wrapped task, then see which one finished first using `Task.WhenAny`; if the delay task finished first then I display
the overlay. Then I await the wrappedTask and hide the overlay.

Comment: Your question was "how to get a Task to return to the UI thread in WPF" and that's what I answered.